# Hacked Receipts Returning Status 0

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

We are validating receipts ON OUR SERVER and we are getting hacked receipts with are returning a status 0!

Here is our server code:

```
 $postData = json_encode(
            array('receipt-data' => $receipt)
        );

        //return $postData;

        // create the cURL request
        $ch = curl_init($endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

        // execute the cURL request and fetch response data
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $errno    = curl_errno($ch);
        $errmsg   = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // ensure the request succeeded
        if ($errno != 0) {
            throw new Exception($errmsg, $errno);
        }

        // parse the response data
        $data = json_decode($response);

        // ensure response data was a valid JSON string
        if (!is_object($data)) {
            return 'Invalid response data';
        }

        // ensure the expected data is present
        if (!isset($data->status) || $data->status != 0) {
            return "Apple return with error ".$data->status;
        }
```

Ive tried placing a bogus data inside the receipt and it will give back a 21002 error (malformed receipt).

I check if the receipt status is 0 and its coming back YES for fake receipts.

Here is a fresh one

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "environment": "Production",
    "receipt": {
        "receipt_type": "Production",
        "adam_id": 813798979,
        "bundle_id": "com.site.gamename",
        "application_version": "0.7",
        "download_id": 81005576413585,
        "request_date": "2014-04-23 21:37:23 Etc/GMT",
        "request_date_ms": "1398289043287",
        "request_date_pst": "2014-04-23 14:37:23 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_purchase_date": "2014-04-21 20:36:09 Etc/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1398112569000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2014-04-21 13:36:09 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_application_version": "0.7",
        "in_app": []
    }
}
```

**STATUS = 0!!! How is this possible!?**

And heres the bogus transaction ID it came with

`84091B08-4706-4810-924F-BC10CC1B`

What the hell can I do?

Whats going on!? How am I getting status 0 from these hacked receipts?!

Comment: The obvious answer is that it is a valid receipt that is being re-played. The receipt verification process you are using doesn't correlate the purchase with anything else.  You can strengthen the in-app purchase process by having another identifier for your user and correlating the two.  In the example you have given, the request date and original purchase date vary significantly, indicating that this is a "restore" - if you didn't have a correlation in your database for the original purchase you could reject it as fraudulent.

Comment: Great suggestion Ill look into this immediately thank you

Comment: @Paulw11: That’s thrice as eligible as an answer than the average response. Why don’t you put it in an answer? Despite its age, it’ll be helpful to future users.